# How to have text placed onto negative y point in subplot

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I want to plot some data I have (square wave signals) in a subplot but I want to remove the axis for better visualization. This results in not having a ylabel. I thought I could add a simple `text()` so I could manually insert the text I want, but I can't seem to be able to use negative values for the y axis (as I could without a subplot). The code I thought would work was:

```py
fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4, ax5, ax6)= plt.subplots(6,1)

#plot
ax1.plot(PathClockGeneration_4.q2bar_x,PathClockGeneration_4.clk_y, linewidth=2, color='black')
ax2.plot(PathClockGeneration_4.q2bar_x,PathClockGeneration_4.clkbar_y, linewidth=2, color='black')
ax3.plot(PathClockGeneration_4.q2bar_x,PathClockGeneration_4.q1_y, linewidth=2, color='C0')
ax4.plot(PathClockGeneration_4.q2bar_x,PathClockGeneration_4.q2_y, linewidth=2, color='C1')
ax5.plot(PathClockGeneration_4.q2bar_x,PathClockGeneration_4.q1bar_y, linewidth=2, color='C2')
ax6.plot(PathClockGeneration_4.q2bar_x,PathClockGeneration_4.q2bar_y, linewidth=2, color='C3')

#axis
ax1.axis('off')
ax2.axis('off')
ax3.axis('off')
ax4.axis('off')
ax5.axis('off')
ax6.axis('off')


#text
ax1.text(-1.5, 2, 'MyText')
```

If i try the last line as `ax1.text(0, 2, 'MyText')` it works fine, but the placement of the text is not the one I want. I suppose this comes from the size my plot is allowed to have and I would need to change it, how to do so?

**EDIT**

This is what I obtain [hiding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxmBy.png) the axis manually (which can allow me to insert a ylabel). [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZYE1.png) is what I really want as plot obtained from the coded posted above by commenting `ax1.text(-1.5, 2, 'MyText')`

Comment: How so, using the answer from this question I still have the frames of the plot even if the ticks are hidden. I want to fully hide anything related. You can see in the edit of the post what I want and what I obtain through the answer you've posted.

Comment: Your code is producing the correct plot which you **really want**. What exactly is the problem. Please explain properly what you want. Where do you want to put the text, what orientation, horizontal, vertical, rotated? Unless you clear these doubts, people will have hard time helping you. You have anyway not provided a runnable code. Above that, if readers don't even know what to solve for, how will they answer. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: When I use you code, everything including the ticks are hidden.

Comment: I want to be able to add a text close to the left side of each plot. Such as ylabel. By using `axis('off')` I can't use ylabel to do so because it is hidden, I generally manage to solve this by using `text(-yplacement, xplacemet, 'text')` with normal plots, however by using subplot I can't seem to be able to use a negative `yplacement` in the `text()` method. Sorry for the first comment saying I was getting exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @GuilhermeTheis : Ok, check the answer below and tell me if that is what you are after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `fig` instead of the `ax1` to place your text. The arguments `0.05, 0.6` are the x and y coordinates in relative scale. You can choose them as per your taste.

---

---

**Complete answer**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4, ax5, ax6) = plt.subplots(6,1)

x = np.linspace(0, 4*np.pi, 100)
y = np.sin(x)
ax1.plot(x, y, linewidth=2, color='black')
ax2.plot(x, y, linewidth=2, color='black')
ax3.plot(x, y, linewidth=2, color='C0')
ax4.plot(x, y, linewidth=2, color='C1')
ax5.plot(x, y, linewidth=2, color='C2')
ax6.plot(x, y, linewidth=2, color='C3')

# Hiding axis
for ax in [ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4, ax5, ax6]:
    ax.axis('off')

fig.text(0.05, 0.6, 'MyText', rotation=90, fontsize=20)
plt.show()
```

[image]